# How to get the output from ffmpeg into python?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script that does a 2-pass `loudnorm` on video files among other things.

But I am unable to get the info from 1-pass into my python script, it only prints to the screen.

I tried `check_output` with no success.

Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL, run, check_output

srcFile = 'test.webm'

command = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', str(srcFile), '-vn', '-pass', '1', '-filter:a', 'loudnorm=print_format=json', '-f', 'webm', '/dev/null']

firstPass = check_output(command)
result = firstPass.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['']
```

While `ffmpeg` does print the `loudnorm` 1-pass info to the screen I can't load it into my python script.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be writing on `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Try adding `stderr=PIPE` as an argument to `check_output()`.

Comment: What _is_ this "loudnorm 1-pass info"? If it's something that would be typically considered "diagnostic" in nature, stderr is the place where the POSIX specification indicates that it _should_ be sent. (stdout is intended for _actual output_; in the case of ffmpeg, its actual output is MPEG-encoded data -- though granted, most or all usage modes send that data directly to a file).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `firstPass = run(command, stderr=PIPE)` totally worked.

`loudnorm 1-pass info`: I am asking ffmpeg to run `loudnorm` filter on audio and to print the information it gleaned from the process to the shell. ffmpeg choose `stderr` to print it. Never would have gussed. Always thought of `stderr` as something ominous.

Comment: Ah. Nope, nothing ominous; stderr is even where bash prints the prompt -- anything that's more about giving humans informational data than about emitting the content your program was started to generate goes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.7 solution:

```
import subprocess

srcFile = 'test.webm'
command = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', str(srcFile), '-vn', '-pass', '1', '-filter:a', 'loudnorm=print_format=json', '-f', 'webm', '/dev/null']
commandout = subprocess.run(command, check=True, capture_output=True).stderr
result = commandout.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
print(result)
```

Example ouput with 'ffprobe' (have stderr):

```
['ffprobe version 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers\r', '  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)\r', '  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint\r', '  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100\r', '  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100\r', '  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100\r', '  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100\r', '  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100\r', '  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100\r', '  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100\r', '  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100\r', "Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Voz 024_sd.m4a':\r", '  Metadata:\r', '    major_brand     : 3gp4\r', '    minor_version   : 0\r', '    compatible_brands: isom3gp4\r', '    creation_time   : 2022-09-06T22:48:56.000000Z\r', '    com.android.version: 12\r', '  Duration: 01:10:25.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 130 kb/s\r', '  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)\r', '    Metadata:\r', '      creation_time   : 2022-09-06T22:48:56.000000Z\r', '      handler_name    : SoundHandle\r', '      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]\r', '']
```

I share it because it is a headache, maybe it will help some lucky one.